# Unable to declare an associative array in Bash

Tags: bash, associative-array

The following line in a bash script:

`declare -A aa`

results in the following error:

`./test: line 57: declare: -A: invalid option`

Which I would have expected if I were running pre v4, but I'm on OS X Sierra 10.12.6 running GNU Bash 4.4.12.

Comment: You're clearly *not* running bash 4.4.12.

Comment: Are you sure you're running that Bash? What's your shebang line (the first line in the script)? Run that path with `--version`.

Comment: Note that OS X Sierra ships bash 3.2 (because Apple refuses to accept GPLv3 licensing). If you're using `/bin/bash`, then you have the one Apple shipped you, not what MacPorts or Homebrew installed.

Comment: I bet it's a `#!/bin/bash` vs `#!/usr/bin/env bash` problem.

Comment: Can you show us what `test`'s contents look like (mostly the shebang)?

Comment: Put `echo "$BASH_VERSION"` in your script, next to the failing line, so we get the actual value at runtime.

Comment: (...so, you can't trust `bash --version` to match `/bin/bash --version`).

Comment: And, ahem, my I point to my answer in the duplicate, which seems to address this exact scenario.

Comment: Thanks everyone, yes, ends up my question is a duplicate to the one posted up to. Strangely it didn't show up in my search (and still doesn't even when I put the exact title in).  

Regardless, I did need to change `#!/bin/bash` to `#!/usr/bin/env bash`. Thanks @BenjaminW.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Output I get was: `4.4.12(1)-release`

Comment: From `bash --version`:  `GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16.3.0)`

Comment: @Jalakoo, not from `bash --version`, not from your interactive shell, but from `echo "$BASH_VERSION"` **when it's actually in your script, right next to the `declare -A` that fails**? (I specified "next to the failing line" in my original comment for a reason).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, that was the output when `echo "$BASH_VERSION"` was placed in the script, not from terminal's interactive shell.

Comment: That output would make sense *if* you'd already fixed the shebang. On MacOS 10.12.6, `/bin/bash -c 'echo "$BASH_VERSION"'` emits `3.2.57(1)-release`.